# Creating KPI Status Indicators with Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, kpi, indicator

I am trying to use calculated columns to have a possibility of 3 status indicators come up based on another column that is called projectstartday which shows how many days are left until a project needs to begin. I have been able to get green and red indicators, but not yellow using the following formula I think just because I don't know how to format the formula to add the other condition ;

=IF(DaysUntilProjectStart>=90,"

I know that  img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF' returns yellow, but do not know how to get it in the formula. I want the calculated field to return the following;

Show red in the sharepoint list: if ProjectStartDate is Less than or equal to 30 
Show Yellow: if ProjectStartDate is Greater than 30 but less than or equal to 90
Show Green: If ProjectStartDate is Greater than 90

I have been trying to figure this out for forever now and would appreciate any help anyone can give me!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

use below in calculated column:

```
="<DIV><img src='"&IF(DaysUntilProjectStart<=30,"/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF",IF(AND(DaysUntilProjectStart>30,DaysUntilProjectStart<=90),"/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF",IF(DaysUntilProjectStart>90,"/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF")))&"'></DIV>"
```

Assuming **DaysUntilProjectStart** is a number field

Comment: Can the number be a calculated field?